# How does write-invalidate policy work with set-associative caches?

Tags: caching, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache, micro-architecture

I was going through [Cache Write Policies](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.457.9642&rep=rep1&type=pdf) paper by Norman P. Jouppi and I understand why write-invalidate (defined on page 193) works well with direct mapped caches which is because of the ability to write the data which checking the tag and if found to be miss, the cache line is invalidates as it is corrupted by the write. This can be done in one cycle.
But is there any benefit if write-invalidate is used for set-associative caches?
What is the usual configuration that is used for L1 caches in real processors? Do they use direct or set-associative and write-validate/write around/write invalidate/fetch-on-write policy?

Answer (score 2):

**TL:DR:** for a non-blocking cache using write-invalidate, changing it from direct-mapped to set-associative could *hurt* the hit rate unless writes are very rare, or mean that you introduce the possibility of needing to block.

Write-invalidate only makes sense for a simple in-order pipeline with a simple cache that tries to avoid stalling the pipeline even without a store buffer, and go really fast at the expense of hit-rate.  If you were going to change things to improve hit-rate, changing away from write-invalidate (usually to write-back + write-allocate + fetch-on-write) would be one of the first things.  Write-invalidate with set-associative cache is possible with some ugly tradeoffs, but you wouldn't like the results.

---

The 1993 paper you linked is using that term to mean something other than [the modern cache-coherence mechanism meaning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_coherence#Coherence_mechanisms).  In the paper:

> The combination of
> write-before-hit, no-fetch-on-write, and no-write-allocate
> we call write-invalidate

Yes, real-world caches these days are basically always set-associative; the more complex tag-comparator logic is worth the increased hit-rate for the same data size.  [Which cache mapping technique is used in intel core i7 processor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49092541/which-cache-mapping-technique-is-used-in-intel-core-i7-processor) has some general stuff, not just x86. Modern examples of direct-mapped caches include the DRAM cache when a part of the persistent memory on an Intel platform operates in memory mode. Also many server-grade processors from multiple vendors support L3 way-wise partitioning, so you can, for example, allocate one way for a thread which would basically behave like a direct-mapped cache.

Write policy is usually write-allocate + fetch-on-write + no-write-before-hit for modern CPU caches; some ISAs offer methods such as special instructions to bypass cache for "non-temporal" stores that won't be re-read soon, to avoid cache pollution for those cases.  Most workloads do re-load their stores with enough temporal locality that write-allocate is the only sane choice, especially when caches are larger and/or more associative so they're more likely to be able to hang onto a line until the next read or write.

It's also very common to do multiple small writes into the same line, making write-allocate *very* valuable, especially if a store buffer didn't manage to merge those writes.

---

> But is there any benefit if write-invalidate is used for set-associative caches?

**It doesn't seem so.**

The only advantage it has is not stalling a simple in-order pipeline that lacks a store buffer ("write buffer" in the paper).  It allows write in parallel with the tag-check, so you find out *after* modifying the line whether you hit or not.  (Modern CPUs *do* use a store buffer to [decouple store commit to L1d from store execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64141366/can-a-speculatively-executed-cpu-branch-contain-opcodes-that-access-ram) and hide store-miss latency.  Even in-order CPUs typically have a store buffer to allow memory-level parallelism of RFOs (read-for-ownership).  (e.g. ARM Cortex-A53 found in phones).

Anyway, **in a set-associative cache, you need to check tags to know which "way" of the set to write into on a write hit.**  (Or detect a miss and pick one to evict according to some policy, like random or pseudo-LRU using some extra state bits, or write-around if no-write-allocate).  **If you wait until after the tag check to find the write way, you've lost the only benefit of write-invalidate**.

Blindly writing to a random way could lead to a situation where there's a hit in a different way than the one you guessed.  Way-prediction is a thing (and can do better than random), but the downside of an incorrect prediction for a write like this would be unnecessarily invalidating a line, instead of just a bit of extra latency.  [Way prediction in modern cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64183414/way-prediction-in-modern-cache).  I don't know what kind of success-rate way-prediction usually achieves.  I'd guess not great, like maybe 80 to 90% at best. Probably spending transistors to do way-prediction would be better spent elsewhere, to do something that sucks less than write-invalidate!  A store buffer with store forwarding probably costs more, but is a lot better.

The advantage of write-invalidate is to help make the cache non-blocking.  But if you need to correct the situation when you do find a write-hit in a way other than the one you picked, you need to go back and correct the situation, updating the correct line.  So you'd lose the non-blocking property.  *Never* stalling is better than not *usually* stalling, because it means you don't even need to make the hardware handle that possible case at all.  (Although you do need to be able to stall for memory.)

The write-in-one-way-hit-in-another situation can be avoided by writing in all of the ways. But there will be at most one hit and the rest will have to be invalidated. The negative impact on hit rate will significantly grow with associativity. (Unless writes are quite infrequent vs. reads, reducing the associativity would probably *help* hit rate with the write-all-ways strategy, so for a given total cache capacity, direct-mapped might be the best choice if you insist on fully-non-blocking write-invalidate.)  Even for a direct-mapped cache, the experimental evaluation given in the paper itself shows that write-invalidate has higher miss rate compare to the other evaluated write policies. So it's win only if the benefits of reducing latency and bandwidth demand outweighs the damage of high miss rate.

Also, as I said, **write-allocate is very good for CPUs**, especially when it's set-associative so you're spending more resources trying to get a higher hit-rate.  You could maybe still implement write-allocate by triggering a fetch on miss, remembering where in the line you stored the data, and merging that with the old copy of the line when it arrives.

You don't want to defeat that by blowing away lines that didn't need to die.

Also, **write-invalidate implies write-through even for write hits**, because it could lose data if a line is ever dirty.  **But write-back is also very good in modern L1d caches** to insulate larger/slower caches from the write bandwidth.  (Especially if there's no per-core private L2 to separately reduce total traffic to shared caches.)  However, AMD Bulldozer-family did have a write-through L1d with a small 4k write-buffer between it and a write-back L2.  This was generally considered a failed experiment or weak point of the design, and they dropped it in favour of a standard write-back write-allocate L1d for Zen.  [When use write-through cache policy for pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61129142/when-use-write-through-cache-policy-for-pages).

**So in summary, write-invalidate is incompatible with several things that modern mainstream CPU designs have settled on as the best options, that you'll find in most mainstream CPU designs**

- write-allocate write policy
- write-back (not write-through).  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_(computing)#Writing_policies
- set-associative (huge downsides that can only be partially mitigated by way-prediction)
- store buffer to decouple store miss from execution, and allow memory parallelism.  (Not strictly incompatible, but a store buffer makes it pointless.  Necessary for OoO exec and widely used for in-order)

---

### write-invalidate in cache-coherent SMP systems

You'd never consider using it in a single-chip multi-core CPU; spend more transistors on each core to get more of the low-hanging fruit before you start building more cores.  e.g. a proper store buffer.  Use some flavour of SMT if you want high throughput for multiple low-IPC threads that stall a lot.

But for multi-socket SMP, this could have made sense historically if you want to use multiple of the biggest single-core chip you can build, and that was still not big enough to just have a store buffer instead of this.

**I guess it could even make sense to use a really "thin" direct-mapped write-through L1d in front of a private medium-sized write-back set-associative L2 that's still pretty fast**.  (Maybe call this an L0d cache because **it can act *like* an unordered store buffer**.  The next-level cache will still see a lot of reads and writes from the low hit-rate of this small direct-mapped cache.)

Normally all caches (including L1d) are part of the same global coherency domain so writing into L1d cache can't happen until you have exclusive ownership.  (Which you check for as part of the tag check.)  But if this L1d / L0d is not like that, then it's not coherent and is more like a store buffer.

Of course, you need to queue the write-throughs for L2, and eventually stall when it can't keep up, so you're just adding complexity.  The write-through to L2 mechanism would also need to deal with waiting for L2 to gain exclusive ownership of the line before writing ([MESI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MESI_protocol) Exclusive or Modified state).  So this is very much just an unordered store buffer.

The case of writing to a line that *hadn't* made it to L2 yet is interesting: if it's an L0d write hit you effectively get store merging for free.  You'd need per-word or per-byte needs-writeback bits (aka dirty bits) for this.  Normally write-through would be sending along the write while the offset within line is still available, but if L2 isn't ready to accept it yet (e.g. because of a write miss) then you can't do that.  This is morphing it into a write-combining buffer.  Marking the whole line as needing write-back doesn't work because the unwritten parts are still invalid.

But if it's a write miss (same cache line, different tag bits) on a line that still hasn't finished write-back to L2, you have a big problem because you'd be invalidating a line that's still "dirty" (has the only copy of some older store data).  You can't detect that before writing; the whole point is to write in parallel with checking tags.

It might be possible to still make this work: if the cache access is a read+write exchange that keeps the previous value in a one-word buffer (or whatever the max write size is), you still have all the data.  Stall everything (including writeback of this line so you don't make wrong data globally visible in coherent L2 cache).  Then exchange back, wait for the old state of that L0d line to actually write back to that address, then store the tmp buffer into L0d and update the tag and needs-writeback bits to reflect this store.  So aliasing between nearby stores becomes extra costly and stalls the pipeline.  Or maybe you can let non-memory instructions continue and only stall execution at the *next* load or store.  (If you have the transistor budget to do much of that stall-avoidance, you can probably just use a completely different strategy, like having a store buffer and a normal L1d.)

To be usable (assuming you work around the dirty-store-miss problem), you'd need some way to track relative order of stores (and loads).  If that's as simplistic as making sure every entry in the entire L0d has finished its write-through process before allowing another write, then even store-store barriers will be very expensive.  The less order-tracking a CPU does, the more expensive barriers have to be (flush more stuff to make sure).

Comment: The write invalidate policy referred to in the question is not related to cache coherence, rather to the write miss policy. See the paper I linked in the question to get the full context of the question.

Comment: @HadiBrais: thanks, updated.  That makes the question make more sense; I guess talking about taxonomies of details for no-write-allocate policies.  Not sure what the point of "write-before-hit" is in that case, why corrupt a perfectly good cache line if you're not going to replace it.  Maybe just included for completeness.  Ah, the paper mentions later that practical implementation considerations like non-blocking (pipelining?) could favour that.  I think they're considering an in-order pipeline maybe without a store buffer + store-forwarding.

Comment: ... given discussion of a "MEM pipeline stage" and aging a store 1 cycle to be sure it completes without an exception.

Comment: Yeah it appears so.  Performing the write concurrently with the tag check may save 1 cycle, so an in-order pipeline without a store buffer (called write buffer in the paper) doesn't need to potentially stall for 1 cycle. Write-invalidate also eliminate the need to stall until the line is fetched on a miss (the paper assumes in the first page that the write doesn't complete until the line is fetched in fetch-on-write policy). Note that your answer only attempts to address the last two parts of the question.

Comment: @HadiBrais: Your prodding got me interested enough to write more and answer the first part: is it useful with set-associative.  So thanks, I guess :P

Comment: That paragraph about compatibility with MESI looks wrong. Write-invalidate can be basically treated like a write-through cache, you don't need M or E states, but still you've to send invalidations to make sure that there is only one global state.

Comment: @HadiBrais: Thanks, that was left over from an earlier iteration of my thinking about if/how it could work, before realizing it could be non-coherent like I talked about later. And I got lazy in my final read-through before posting that edit.  Thanks for your other edits, interesting idea to write all ways of a set.  That would be total garbage unless writes were rare vs. reads, and would probably make lower associativity (even down to 1) better for overall hit rate on many workloads, increasing effective useful capacity.