# What goes under the hood when a x86 processor accesses memory

Tags: memory-management, x86, paging

I'm going through different material to understand what's the behavior when a x86 instruction access memory (implicitly or explicitly).
So far, I believe this is the step-by-step process:

- Effective address is calculated based on the DS,
- If page containing the address is not present:

  - The TLB is checked for the page containing the address to be accessed,

    - If not present in the TLB: the MMU translates the virtual address to a physical address
    - add the new translation to the TLB
  - Load the page
- Access the page

Is this correct? What am I missing?

Comment: Terminology: "effective address" is just the "offset" part of a `seg:off` logical address like `ds:[edi + eax*4]`.  What you meant to say is that segmentation produces a *linear* virtual address using the segment base, assuming paging is enabled.  (In 64-bit long mode, paging must be enabled, but DS base is fixed at 0.  FS and GS can still have non-zero bases, allowing their use for thread-local storage.)

Comment: What do you mean "If page containing the address is not present:"?  That's something the CPU figures out by consulting the TLB, falling back to walking the page table on TLB miss.  If the page tables say the page isn't present, a #PF page fault exception is raised.  Then the *OS* is responsible for updating the page tables (after loading the page if necessary) so a retry of the access won't page-fault.  But that's software, not something the CPU does internally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Determine the effective address (i.e., offset).
- Calculate the linear address based on the segment.
- Simultaneously,

  - Check the L1 cache for the line containing the address.
  - Check the TLB for the page containing the address.
  - If both of the above hit and the memory type and access type are cachable, perform the access to the cache. (I'm not going to go into the other memory types.)
- If not present in the TLB (or insufficient permissions),

  - Perform a page walk to translate the virtual address to a physical address.
  - If the page walk fails, raise a page fault.
  - If the page walk succeeds, add the translation to the TLB.
- If the memory type and access type are cachable, acquire the cache line and perform the access to the cache.

Comment: Nitpick: L1 cache is not virtually addressed in any x86, so the TLB result is needed as part of determining an L1 hit.  (Typically VIPT, so tags+data can be fetched from the set based on the index bits of the address in parallel with the TLB lookup, but a hit is determined by comparing tags).  See [VIPT Cache: Connection between TLB & Cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46480015).  Outer levels of cache are PIPT so they just use the physical address generated as part of the attempt to access L1d, if the load misses in L1d.

Comment: (For a store, virtual and then physical address when available are written to the store buffer by the store-address uop, eventually committing the data from the store buffer to that line of L1d cache.  The virtual address provides earlier detection of same-address or non-overlap for memory disambiguation / store forwarding.)