# Is L2 TLBs on the critical path for L1 cache accesses?

Tags: caching, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache, tlb

Considering only dcache and dTLB. Due to the current L1d-cache being VIPT, it is necessary to obtain a physical address before cache hit.

Now, it is sure that the hit judgment of L1d-cache depends on the results of L1 dTLB. [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46480015/vipt-cache-connection-between-tlb-cache)

But what if L1-dTLB misses, do CPU have to wait for the results of L2-TLB to return in order to access the data in L1d-cache?

What if L2-TLB also misses and a page walk is required? Is it unreasonable for the cache access operation to wait for page walks that require memory access?

Comment: The tag-check can't happen until the TLB returns a tag, so yes, L1dTLB misses delay loads.  If you can invent a way for L1d cache access *not* to be delayed while we check L2-TLB or do a page-walk, that would be useful for future CPU designs, so I'm curious why you think that might be possible.  (You could guess and roll back on mis-speculation, but making a useful guess is probably no easier than just having a larger TLB that's non-speculative.)

Comment: If you hit the cache it's because something already brought that line there. And since you need the physical address to read from memory, most of the time the TLB entry is already cached. It's possible that conflict and capacity misses happen in the TLBs of course but then bigger TLBs would be the easier way to tackle this performance problem.

Comment: @PeterCordes In fact, I also believe that it is impossible to determine whether a cache has hit until a valid physical address is obtained through TLB or Page Walk. But on the other hand, I think it is very counterintuitive to perform multiple slow memory accesses (Page walks) before accessing a fast cache. So I speculate whether it is possible to directly determine cache miss once L1-TLB (or L2-TLB) misses, in order to avoid blocking subsequent cache access.

Comment: *in order to avoid blocking subsequent cache access.* - what?  Non-blocking caches (hit-under-miss and/or miss-under-miss) are a thing for both L1d miss and for L1dTLB miss.  This load gets suspended, and retried later (including another access to L1d tags + data) when the L2-TLB hits, or when page-walk completes.  You're right, stalling all other memory access (on that execution unit) until a page walk finished would be total garbage, which is why high performance CPUs don't do it that way.

Comment: Got it, thank you